# Not able to hit too long url in solr which is generate by sitecore

Tags: iis, solr, sitecore

I am using `sitecore 9.1` and there is a field type multilist with search named media and it is having 1000`s of items in the left hand side , when i try to move those items from left to right , after a point when i have moved some 100 - 130 items , the url which is generated for the left side of the field becomes too long that it cannot show the remaining items.

I am using `solr 7.2.1`.

I have tried changing the `web.config` file also.

I have also tried the below

```
<requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="524288000" maxQueryString="1048576" />
httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.1" maxQueryStringLength="1048576"  maxUrlLength="1048576" maxRequestLength="51200000"
```

Comment: Can you try by increasing the limit of maxboolean query clause? This is available in solrconfig.xml

Comment: tried , no luck

Comment: Do you know how long the URL is? By how much you have increased the limit?

Comment: the url is more than 40k characters , and i am able to hit the url upto 30-35k characters only tried this [link](http://tjluis.blogspot.com/2016/06/solved-url-too-long-on-iis-for-good.html) also

Comment: I would suggest to hit the solr multiple times by dividing the filter params...You need to write a logic where in you can decide how many request to send to the solr and once you get the response, merger the same response

Comment: can you give an example of that

Comment: how are you connecting to solr? is it by using the http call? are you using c# or java?

Comment: using c# and http call

Comment: If you're making these requests yourself, use `POST` requests.